# Detect button press inside embedded view using Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvm, uiview, xamarin.ios

I'm fairly new to building apps using Xamarin for iOS...

I have a view (view1) that contains another view (view2) with a few buttons inside it. Is it possible to detect if a button on the second view has been pressed from the first view?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can do this. make buttons on view2 to public. and then add target action for that button from view1.

e.g. Write following on view1 class:

```
view2.button.TouchUpInside += ButtonClicked;


public void ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I just needed to add a `ButtonEvent EventHandler` like so: 

`EventHandler ButtonEvent = new EventHandler(ButtonClicked);
view2.button1.TouchUpInside += ButtonEvent;`

Method containing code that is executed on button pressed:

`public void ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //Do something...
}`